# firebase auth with MIcrosoft Graph (accessToken)

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am super hopeful someone can help me - I'm kind of stuck.

I'm happily using firebase auth with Microsoft AD. My AuthProvider is `firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com')`.

When I call `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup()` with that provider, everything works GREAT. I can pick out the `accessToken` from the resulting `UserCredential` and access Microsoft Graph api's no problem (yay!).

Firebase persists and renews the authentication and my app gets the expected callback via `onAuthStateChanged` with the new `firebase.User` when the user returns to my SPA later (also yay!).

The *bad news* (where I'm stuck) is: *how do I get the Microsoft Graph `accessToken` in this flow* (e.g. when the user returns to my app later)? I don't want them to have to re-authenticate with another popup (yech).

Basically, how do I go from a valid `firebase.User` to a MS Graph `accessToken` when the user returns?

Thanks so so much for any help!

Comment: Did you find any suitable solution to always get the `accessToken` (especially for returning users)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE/answer: so it turns out to be simpler than I thought:

The basic idea is to authenticate (re-authenticate) using firebase and use the *same clientID* for silent microsoft authentication. However, you *must* supply a `loginHint`
parameter to the microsoft auth, even if you were previously authorized. loginHint can
be the email address for the firebase user...

In that scenario, the authentication is shared and you won't need to popup a second sign-in for the "microsoft half" of the process - the firebase auth works fine.

I ended up using microsoft's MSAL library (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)... something like this:

```js
const graphDebug = false;
const msalLogger = new Logger(msalLogCallback, { level: LogLevel.Error });

export async function graphClient(loginHint: string) {
  const msal = new UserAgentApplication({
    // gotcha: MUST set the redirectUri, otherwise get weird errors when msal
    // tries to refresh an expired token.
    auth: { clientId: CLIENT_ID, redirectUri: window.location.origin },
    system: { logger: msalLogger },
    // TODO: should we set cache location to session/cookie?
  });

  /**
   * Create an authprovider for use in subsequent graph calls. Note that we use
   * the `aquireTokenSilent` mechanism which works because firebase has already
   * authenticated this user once, so we can share the single sign-on.
   *
   * In order for that to work, we must pass a `loginHint` with the user's
   * email. Failure to do that is fatal.
   */
  const authProvider: AuthProvider = callback => {
    msal
      .acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: SCOPES, loginHint })
      .then(result => {
        callback(null, result.accessToken);
      })
      .catch(err => callback(err, null));
  };

  const client = Client.init({
    authProvider,
    debugLogging: graphDebug,
  });

  return client;
}
```

Comment: I wanted just to post the exact same answer to your question! Was dealing with the same problem the last couple of days. I ended up using `myMSALObj.ssoSilent({..})` with the needed scope(s) and the loginHint (being the users email). It's worth mentioning that one needs to configure SPA platform in the Azure App Registration with the respective redirect URI.

Comment: This isn't working for me because `acquireTokenSilent` requires an `auth` object. How can I get that after signing  a user in with firebase?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth only focuses on authentication only. They will return the OAuth access token on sign in success via `UserCredential` but will discard the Microsoft OAuth refresh token and not store any OAuth credential associated with the provider. So you have no way to get a new access token afterwards. If you have a good reason for Firebase Auth to manage OAuth access tokens, please file an [official feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the approach I should use instead is have the 3rd party OAuth provider (e.g. Microsoft AD) do the original auth and then use signInWithCredential() to pass back to firebase auth, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using signInWithPopup, the result object contains the credentials you are looking for.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function(result) {
    // User is signed in.
    // IdP data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile.
    // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
    // result.credential.accessToken
    // OAuth ID token can also be retrieved:
    // result.credential.idToken
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error.
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Amit, that indeed works for the initial signIn, but does not work when the user returns to the app via a persisted firebase user. In that, there seems to be no way to get the accessToken from auth().currentUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you look deep enough you should find msal access token in firebase response under (firebaseAuth.currentUser as zzx).zzj()