# Firebase signInWithCredentials from Microsoft Azure

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

Normally, I'd use the `firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com')` and pass it to `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup()` but in my case I need to log into Microsoft **first** using [their library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and pass the credentials back to firebase. (why? because I need their `accessToken/refreshToken` handling which isn't done by firebase).

Anyway, I can't seem to find a way to take the microsoft-supplied credentials and pass them successfully back to firebase...

here's what's **not** working for me:

```
export async function msLogin() {
  const userAgent = new MSAL.UserAgentApplication({ auth: { clientId: CLIENT_ID, } });
  const auth = await userAgent.loginPopup({ scopes: ['profile'] });
  const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
  const idToken = auth.idToken.rawIdToken;
  const credential = provider.credential(idToken);

  await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential); // **** THIS FAILS
  // ... with "Invalid IdP response/credential: http://localhost?id_token=eyJ0eXAiO...0e9BeTObQ&providerId=microsoft.com"
```

The microsoft popup part works great and I'm logged in successfully there and able to issue API calls. But I can't get firebase to accept those credentials to log in on firebase. I've enabled the Microsoft OAuth provider in the Firebase Authentication panel and I'm sure the CLIENT_ID's match...

Maybe I'm constructing the `OAuthCredential` wrong?

*Help greatly appreciated!*

ps: this is a continuation of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031125/firebase-auth-with-microsoft-graph-accesstoken).

Comment: Did you solve it? Same problem here.

Comment: @lubo08: alas, no BUT I am going to try the auth flow around and use the built-in firebase auth and supply it to MSAL's authProvider so that the token will be refreshed (hopefully!) when it expires... hope to get to that in the next 390 days...

Comment: Thank you :) It looks  like firebase will not support this option right now. And the only way how to achieve this is to have own middleware to generate auth token for a user authenticated on the same middleware to MS. But my goal was to get it running wit electron desktop application.