# Get access token with flutterfire after user is signed in

Tags: flutter, oauth, firebase-authentication, access-token

If I use the `signInWithPopup` method I get a `UserCredential` and I can get an accestoken. But if I have signed in the user and later in the code I want to call an api using the access-token. How do I get the accestoken. I know you can get the ID-token using `User#getIdToken`, is there something simmilar for the accesstoken?

**NOTE**:
I can't just store the accesstoken in a variable, because I want to use it in `userChanges` event. And sometimes the user is already signed in.

**Edit:** I discovered that [firebase auth with MIcrosoft Graph (accessToken)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031125/firebase-auth-with-microsoft-graph-accesstoken) is a bit like my question, but he is doing it with javascipt and I am using flutter. How would I do this silent signin in flutter?